# Was Churchill's "backwards" victory symbol a rude gesture to Hitler?

Tags: world-war-two, churchill

Churchill was sometimes photographed giving the V-for-victory symbol with the back of the hand to the photographer or crowd. Was this meant as a sly "up yours" gesture to Hitler, or just a less common variant of the gesture?

Comment: In absence of any evidence to the contrary, I think its fair to deploy [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) here.

Comment: Or even "a rude gesture to photographers?"

Comment: I don't think a rude gesture to British photographers, who were just documenting the news, giving him and the government "we're all in this together" publicity, and very much "on the war effort team" would be at all in character for Churchill.

Comment: What does it even mean when given with the back of the hand?

Comment: back of the hand - its a rude gesture _allegedly_ first given by medieval archers to their french enemies to show that their bow-drawing hand still worked

Comment: @plocks : It's a UK insult very similar to extending just the middle finger in the USA.  It was common in the 60's and 70's, but the middle finger only has spread here too.

Comment: Thatcher made the same mistake after the Falklands "War" - intended the V for Victory sign and got it backwards - to the delight of the Press!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It [appears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_sign#Second_World_War:_V_for_Victory_campaign) that Churchill was not at first aware of the meaning of the offensive version of the gesture. While he had no title, he was very much an aristocrat, and his insight into the behaviour of the British lower classes was fairly limited. This is plausible: the UK was far more stratified by social class than it is today, which is still quite a lot compared to many other countries.

Once his aides pointed out the meaning of the palm-inwards version of the gesture, he was careful to use the palm-outwards version. The nearness of the gesture to "up yours, Hitler" may well have contributed to its popularity.

There is an earlier incident that shows Churchill being naïve about the British lower classes. When Churchill was First Sea Lord before WWI, he needed to [consult King George V over the names of new battleships](https://winstonchurchill.hillsdale.edu/hms-cromwell-naming-warships/). One of his proposals was HMS Pitt, after one of both of the Prime Ministers of that name. George V rejected that. He had been a naval officer for many years. He knew that sailors use affectionate or mocking nicknames for their ships, the nickname for "Pitt" was just *obvious* and he didn't want it used. Churchill complained about that, but nobody who actually knew sailors agreed with him.

Comment: I'll take your (and of course Wikipedia's :D ) word for it, but I'd be very surprised if public-school (or any) boys of the late 19th century (or any era) weren't familiar with all sorts of obscene topics, speech, and gestures.

Comment: Being naive about the British lower classes, and not being intimately familiar with the common views of sailors, are not at all the same thing.

Comment: You're going to have to help me out here. Pitt? -  "nickname for "Pitt" was just obvious" - um,  not to me it isn't.  Give us a bigger clue!

Comment: @peterG like I said, cesspit, armpit, any pit in general, including https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=arsepit , is what comes to mind here. I wouldn't go much further than that - the source doesn't. FWIW, there's been a dozen of HMS Pitt's during the era, so the reaction to the name is probably similar to the one to *Cromwell* proposition (strongly exaggerated).

Comment: @peterG: The obvious nickname can be obtained by replacing the initial "P" of "Pitt" with "Sh".

Comment: While I'm loathe to trust Hollywood when it comes to history, they made such a point of this very moment in the movie *Darkest Hour* that I'm willing to believe you.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to include the pictures of both gestures and add to the given answer.

The gesture was explained to Churchill many times according to his private secretary and Churchill continued to use both the victory sign and the vulgar sign interchangeable with palm facing both ways before he eventually did confine himself to the victory sign (palm facing outwards).  As for why once informed he continued to use the vulgar gesture, maybe he was not entirely put off the public surmising he was giving Hitler a private vulgar message with the gesture, or perhaps he just had bigger things on his mind at that point early in the war.

[image]

[image]